# ThemeProvider does not change the theme of component, React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I want to apply theme to React Component(Class Component). This theme works fine when i define the `ThemeProvider` and the `CustomComponent` in same file. When i separate the files, it stops working. It does not apply the theme to the component. Code is given below

**ThemedComponent:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const Styles = makeStyles(theme =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "&.Mui-focused": {
        border: "20px solid red",
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          border: "none"
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
class ThemedComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  handlePasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    console.log("I am showing All Props", this.props);
    const { classes } = this.props;
    console.log("I am showing ", classes);
    return (
      <TextField
        onChange={event => this.handlePasswordChange(event)}
        variant="outlined"
        classes={{ root: classes.root }}
        InputProps={{ className: classes.root }}
      />
    );
  }
}
ThemedComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(Styles)(ThemedComponent);
```

**CustomTextField:**

```
import React from "react";
import ThemedComponent from "./ThemedComponent";
import { orange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  status: {
    borderStyle: "20px solid red"
  }
});
function CustomTextField() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ThemedComponent/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default CustomTextField;
```

**App.js:**

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomTextField />
    </div>
  );
```

Here is the link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-meadow-9tj9i?file=/src/App.js)
Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your codesandbox doesn't show anything. Regardless - what is `status` in your theme?

Comment: I have updated the link. Status is just a random variable through which i pass "Border" attribute to "CreateStyles". Right now i have just hardcoded the "Border" in CreateStyles for testing purposes

Comment: "&.Mui-focused": {
        border: "theme.status.borderStyle",
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          border: "none"
        }

Comment: i would use in this way